# Database Over Normalized

Tags: database-design, normalization, denormalization

How can you tell when a database is over normalized? Example: I have a database for employee. These are the following tables involved:

> User - contains email, password, companyId
>
> Profile - profile of the employee (first name, last name, address)
>
> Group - Department list
>
> Company - list of companies
>
> Position - List of positions
>
> Employee - employee information like id numbers, height, weight, contract info, etc.

Comment: Over normalized?  Only you can decide that.  If it makes sense for the system to have those tables, and performance is at the desired level, then fine, otherwise make some changes.

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't believe what you've posted is over-normalised. You could normalise further, like taking the address out of employee profile as employees could share an address...Like Max says, it really depends on whether or not you're happy with performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if it ain't broke, don't fix it. If no-one is complaining about the speed of the system then leave it alone. Spend time and money on other things.

Second, no, I don't think it is possible to over-normalise. That is, I think it is possible to spend more time on the normalisation process than your application might need, but unless you've spent tens and tens and tens of hours doing so I don't think the time is really wasted. The time getting to 3rd normal form is most certainly never wasted.

In my (admittedly limited) experience, the problem is usually under-normalisation, otherwise known as "laziness". Database designers often claim it is for speed purposes, throwing the term "denormalised" about like a holy mantra, but if you investigate closely, all they've actually done is half a job.

Denormalisation is not "stopping before you reach a certain normal form"; it is "reaching a certain form (usually 3NF or BCNF) and then undoing some of that normalisation for well-documented, well-benchmarked reasons."

Links

Tony Davis, [The myth of over-normalization](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2008/07/21/the-myth-of-over-normalization/).

Louis Davidson, [Can you over-normalize?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2010/04/29/can-you-over-normalize.aspx).